# Last Character Issue with SAP HANA UTF8 on PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, hana, unixodbc

For some reason the last character of a UTF8 string is getting messed  but only on linux. Works just fine on windows. Here is the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain;Charset=UTF-8;');
$datasource = 'DRIVER=/usr/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.so;SERVERNODE=myserver:30041;CHAR_AS_UTF8=TRUE;';
$username   = "myuser";
$password   = "mypass";

$conn   = odbc_connect($datasource, $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

if (!($conn)) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
} 
else {
    $sql = 'select * from sltschema.t141t';
    $rs  = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }       
    while ($rec=(array)odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo json_encode($rec).PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
    odbc_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Here are the results on my CENTOS Linux box (notice last character in MTSTB)

```
{
MANDT: "000",
SPRAS: "1",
MMSTA: "01",
MTSTB: "因采购/仓库而被冻hp",
ZMODIFIEDTS: "20200120110440737"
}
```

Here are the results on my Windows Box (only changed DRIVER={HDBODBC} in datasource)

```
{
MANDT: "000",
SPRAS: "1",
MMSTA: "01",
MTSTB: "因采购/仓库而被冻结",
ZMODIFIEDTS: "20200120110440737"
}
```

So somehow only the last character is getting messed up.

Any suggestions?

PS: I am using version 2.4.182.1579711187 of the HDBclient driver and have tried version 2.0.62.1478878744 with the same issue.

Comment: BTW, I am using version 2.4.182.1579711187  of the HDBclient driver and have tried version 2.0.62.1478878744 with the same issue.

Comment: Can it be Windows ODBC driver issue? Have you tried other drivers?

Comment: It works on windows, just not on linux. I have tried other versions of the linux driver but they all have the same issue.

Comment: SAP recommends installing HANA client [from here](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/) (or from [Marketplace](https://www.hanatutorials.com/p/install-hana-client-on-windows.html)), there the latest version for Linux is 2.4.171. You seems to use some beta from Centos repos which may be buggy and unstable

Comment: Can you reproduce this faulty behavior with standard ODBC clients, e.g. *isql*?

Comment: Lars, thank you for the suggestion. If I use isql I get the correct response.  So is this a PHP issue?

  +------+------+------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| MANDT| SPRAS| MMSTA| MTSTB                    | ZMODIFIEDTS                |
+------+------+------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| 000  | 1    | 01   | 因采购/仓库而被冻| 20200120110440737          |

Comment: I upgraded PHP from 7.1 to 7.3.14 to rule out a bad PHP version. Same problem.

Comment: I wrote a script using python 2.7 using the same ODBC.ini and it returned correct data.  因采购/仓库而被冻结
因任务清单/BOM而被冻结
MPN:BOM抬头冻结
gesp. für Besch./Lager
gesp. für Arb.plan/Stückl
   This leads me to conclude that it is a PHP ODBC issue and not a HANA driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a bug to PHP.net on this:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79217

I also found another interesing bit of information: 
The field I am querying is set to nvarchar(25) in HANA.  If I cast it as nvarchar(50) it works.

### test query:

```
select cast(mtstb as nvarchar(50)) mtstb  from sltschema.t141t
```

### Results:

```
Mtstb
因采购/仓库而被冻结
因任务清单/BOM而被冻结
MPN:BOM抬头冻结
gesp. für Besch./Lager
gesp. für Arb.plan/Stückl
```

Comment: Very good! This reads like PHP sometimes cuts off data at the end of strings. Have you tested it with just one additional character for size ?